# Finding Neural Network ROC in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network, roc, nnet

I am trying to create an ROC plot for a neural net. I can't seem to get it to work. I get the error. I am using the packages nnet, and verification for the ROC curve.

```
Error in text.default(DAT[id, 3, i], DAT[id, 2, i], plot.thres[id2], pos = 4,  :
```

zero-length 'labels' specified

The Code for the ROC is:

```
roc.plot(yelp_test$open == "1", outsample_nnet)
roc.plot(yelp_test$open == "1", outsample_nnet)$roc.vol
```

The Out sample code is:

```
outsample_nnet<- predict(Yelp_net, yelp_test, type="raw") 
outsample_nnet <- outsample_nnet > 0.5
outsample_nnet <- as.numeric(outsample_nnet) 
nnets_table <- table(yelp_test$open, outsample_nnet, dnn = c("Truth", "Predicted"))
```

dput code for the 30 obs is: 
    newdata <- cleanDataFrame[2:10]
    set.seed(10)
    (newdata[sample(1:nrow(newdata), 30),])

```
 structure(list(open = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), review_count = c(3L, 5L, 6L, 38L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 
23L, 19L, 3L, 22L, 74L, 15L, 38L, 88L, 26L, 9L, 3L, 58L, 4L, 
13L, 117L, 38L, 10L, 5L, 6L, 102L, 108L, 264L, 103L), stars = c(3, 
4, 4.5, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4, 2.5, 3.5, 
3.5, 3.5, 4, 3, 4.5, 4.5, 4, 3.5, 4, 3.5, 4, 3, 3.5, 4), Freq = c(166L, 
12L, 166L, 15L, 45L, 166L, 66L, 79L, 33L, 58L, 150L, 389L, 150L, 
1L, 389L, 20L, 389L, 389L, 389L, 166L, 74L, 0L, 389L, 32L, 389L, 
161L, 126L, 389L, 98L, 3L), avgRev = c(23.7904191616766, 18.7692307692308, 
23.7904191616766, 98, 78.804347826087, 23.7904191616766, 31.3283582089552, 
64.3375, 23.1764705882353, 23.6949152542373, 60.6490066225166, 
34.1923076923077, 60.6490066225166, 22, 34.1923076923077, 33.1904761904762, 
34.1923076923077, 34.1923076923077, 34.1923076923077, 30.8443113772455, 
27.6533333333333, 117, 34.1923076923077, 30.4545454545455, 34.1923076923077, 
37.2716049382716, 47.3149606299213, 34.1923076923077, 64.3838383838384, 
73.75), avgStar = c(3.53592814371257, 3.92307692307692, 3.53592814371257, 
3.96875, 3.6195652173913, 3.53592814371257, 3.69402985074627, 
3.58125, 3.5, 3.67796610169492, 3.63245033112583, 3.5551282051282, 
3.63245033112583, 4, 3.5551282051282, 3.78571428571429, 3.5551282051282, 
3.5551282051282, 3.5551282051282, 3.48203592814371, 3.72666666666667, 
4.5, 3.5551282051282, 3.65151515151515, 3.5551282051282, 3.43827160493827, 
3.63385826771654, 3.5551282051282, 3.60606060606061, 4.25), count = c(4L, 
2L, 5L, 5L, 0L, 2L, 5L, 0L, 2L, 8L, 3L, 15L, 4L, 3L, 15L, 14L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 50L, 1L, 27L, 4L, 51L, 36L, 14L), 
recession = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), duration = c(332L, 427L, 614L, 117L, 1894L, 
1346L, 140L, 1909L, 1100L, 1030L, 1666L, 2096L, 1054L, 352L, 
2145L, 1018L, 1763L, 391L, 2116L, 1567L, 693L, 674L, 1626L, 
301L, 295L, 378L, 649L, 376L, 1028L, 2390L)), .Names = c("open", 
"review_count", "stars", "Freq", "avgRev", "avgStar", "count", 
"recession", "duration"), row.names = c(1439L, 870L, 1210L, 1962L, 
242L, 639L, 777L, 771L, 1741L, 1214L, 1840L, 1603L, 322L, 1681L, 
1010L, 1209L, 148L, 745L, 1124L, 2354L, 2433L, 1731L, 2180L, 
1000L, 1141L, 1985L, 2814L, 674L, 2163L, 999L), class = "data.frame")
```

The recession variable in this sample did not contain any 1's. I arbitrarily added a 1 to to the last observation to ensure the code works.

Comment: which package are you using?

Comment: nnet, and verification.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?